# How to print combined var name in python 3.7

Tags: python

I would like to print new_firstsecond's value, without knowing it's name in advance, how can I do this in python 3.7?

```
var1 = "first"
var2 = "second"

new_firstsecond = "some value"

print("new_"+f"{vars()[var1]}"+f"{vars()[var2]}")
```

Comment: Just use ```globals()[f"new_{var1}{var2}"]```

Comment: you got your answer, what I want to know is "why"?

Comment: Yeah I'm also curious :D

Comment: Thank you. The reason I need this is because I'm connected to a webserver, and I'm getting thousand of lines every sec. I need to sort them by one of their keys, without knowing what those keys are in advance.

Comment: Whenever you need to constructed variable named you probably should use a dictionary or some other container structure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

```
var1 = "first"
var2 = "second"

new_firstsecond = "some value"

for variable, value in globals().copy().items():
    print(variable, value)
```